# Vuelidate: Conditionally adding validation models

Tags: validation, vue.js, vuejs2, vuelidate

I recently made the switch with Vuelidate from Vee-Validate a few weeks ago for all our apps and have been loving its flexibility so far; however, I've run across an issue that I'm not quite sure how to solve...

I've added the (primitive) example, using my real data here:

https://jsfiddle.net/80cuuagp/18/

From the fiddle:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
        questions: [
        {
          message: '1. Do you expect to conduct cash transactions for this account? ',
          value: false,
          conditionalFields: [
            {
              title: 'Cash In',
              fields: [
                { label: 'Total Amount', value: '' },
                { label: 'Frequency', value: '' }
              ]
            },
            {
              title: 'Cash Out',
              fields: [
                { label: 'Total Amount', value: '' },
                { label: 'Frequency', value: '' }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          message: '2. Will Electronic (ACH) transactions be processed on the account (excluding card transactions)?',
          value: false,
          conditionalFields: [
            {
              title: 'Electronic Deposits',
              fields: [
                { label: 'Total Amount', value: '' },
                { label: 'Frequency', value: '' }
              ]
            },
            {
              title: 'Electronic Withdrawals',
              fields: [
                { label: 'Total Amount', value: '' },
                { label: 'Frequency', value: '' }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          message: '3. Will Domestic Wires be sent or received from the account?',
          value: false,
          conditionalFields: [
            {
              fields: [
                { label: 'Frequency of Incoming Wires', value: '' }
              ]
            },
            {
              fields: [
                { label: 'Frequency of Outgoing Wires', value: '' },
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          message: '4. Will International Wires be sent or received from the account?',
          value: false,
          conditionalFields: [
            {
              fields: [
                { label: 'Frequency of Incoming Wires', value: '' }
              ]
            },
            {
              fields: [
                { label: 'Frequency of Outgoing Wires', value: '' },
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          message: '5. Will Monetary Instruments (CC/MO) be issued from the account?',
          value: false,
          conditionalFields: [
            {
              fields: [
                { label: 'Total Amount', value: '' }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  validations: {
    questions: {
      $each: {
        conditionalFields: {
          $each: {
            fields: {
              $each: {
                value: { required }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

The problem is - I'm conditionally rendering fields based on the user's input. If he or she selects "Yes" to any of the questions, a secondary fieldset will appear below it and ask for input. These fields are only required if yes is selected and they appear on the DOM (and will also have different validations, which I'm not sure how to address, either without hard-coding everything). I've tried looping through the data by making validations a function, but even though it seems to compile, it's not dynamically adding any validations based on the question[index].value being set to true.

I feel like there has to be a simple way to do this, but I'm definitely overthinking it at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!